# Find a vector $w$ such that $Aw = v_1 + 3v_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

> if $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix and $\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{y_1},\vec{y_2}$ are vectors so that $A\vec{y_1} = \vec{v_1}$ and $A\vec{y_2} = \vec{v_2}$ find a vector $\vec{w}$ so that $A\vec{w} = \vec{v_1} + 3\vec{v_2}$

How can I find this vector $\vec{w}$? I'm so confused. What are they even asking me to do ?

Comment: Hint: replace $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$ by $A\vec{y_1}$ and $A\vec{y_2}$.

Comment: Hint: let ${\bf w}=a_1{\bf y}_1+a_2{\bf y}_2$ where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are scalars.  Multiply out $A{\bf w}$ and simplify.  Can you find values for $a_1,a_2$ such that the answer is ${\bf v}_1+3{\bf v}_2$?

Comment: Ok so $A*w = Aa_1y_1 + a_2y_2$ ?

Comment: so then I can say $Ay_1 = v_1 $ then I can set $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = 3$ with $Ay_2 = v_2$?

Comment: The hints here are referring to the idea of a *linear combination*, an important concept in linear algebra. The image under $A$ of the vector $w$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: So...... what I said was wrong?

Comment: @Yusha, what you have said is correct. $$Aw=v_1+3v_2=Ay_1+3Ay_2=A(y_1+3y_2)$$hence, $w=y_1+3y_2$.

Answer (score 1):

They are asking you to find a parallelogram. Any matrix $A$ represents a linear transformation. So when you apply a matrix $A$ to a vector $v$, you rotate and/or stretch the vector. An important part of this is that the angle between any two vectors is preserved under matrix multiplication. This means that if you apply a matrix to the edges of a parallelogram, you get a parallelogram. Note that the sum of the edges gives you the diagonal of the parallelogram, with the standard orientation.

You are given that $A$ takes $y_{1}$ to $v_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ to $v_{2}$. Since parallelograms are preserved, $A$ takes $y_1 + y_2 $ to $v_1  + v_2$. You want to know what diagonal is taken to $v_1 + 3v_2 $. The latter is the diagonal of the parallelogram determined by the vectors $v_1$ and $3v_2$. So the question becomes what vectors are taken to $v_{1}$ and $3v_2$. You are given that the first vector you're looking for is $y_1$ and the second vector is obviously $y_2$ stretched by $3$.

I like the geometric way but here is the algebra :

$A(y_1+3y_2) = Ay_1 + 3Ay_2 = v_1 + 3v_2$

Answer (score 0):

Use the linearity of matrix multiplication:

$$A(a_1 \vec{x_1} + a_2\vec{x_2}) = a_1 A\vec{x_1} + a_2 A \vec{x_2}$$

Noting that $$A(3\vec{y_2})=3A\vec{y_2} = 3\vec{v_2}$$ and exploiting the linearity property given above, we find that $$A(\vec{y_1}+3\vec{y_2})=A\vec{y_1}+3A\vec{y_2}= \vec{v_1}+3\vec{v_2}$$

Therefore taking $\vec{w}=\vec{y_1}+3\vec{y_2}$ gives the required answer.